# Not sure why my reader won't read my text file

Tags: .net, stream

I have the following code to read a file in the root directory of my application. For some reason, no matter how many runs, my file is still not being read. Any idea what I could be doing wrong here please. Thanks in advance.

```
byte[] mybytes = null;
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filename, 
                               FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
    {
        String input;
        StringBuilder tempstore = new StringBuilder();
        while ((input  = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            tempstore.Append(input);
        }
        mybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tempstore.ToString());
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: may be its going root directory of the drive

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Is it getting past your if (File.Exists(filename))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried File.ReadAllBytes?

```
        byte[] mybytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

Comment: I initially had it as you have it there ( File.ReadAllBytes(filename)) and that did not work. So I switched it over to what I have now and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried File.ReadAllText(filename); ?

It's easier.

Answer (score 0):

ReadLine should only be used with text files. If your file is binary it could have a ^Z character at the beginning.. making the library think that it reached the EOF.

Comment: Good Point, as he is ultimately putting it into `byte[]` this might be the case

Comment: file name actually refers to 

  string filename = @"outfile.txt";

Comment: It doesn't matter. It could be a binary file with extension .txt. Try opening it with Notepad

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me if I copy it verbatim, add my own `filename` variable and run it.  Is it possible that the value of `filename` is not a valid file path on your machine?

Comment: but he is checking `File.Exists(filename)`

Comment: It passes the 

  if (File.Exists(filename)) 
                    { 
...
}
check, indicating that the file does exist, it stops short at the line ...
       while ((input  = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
Where it reads null and breaks out of my loop immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `filename` actually exists?  That is really the most likely thing that could be the problem based on the code you've listed.